# Aliasing issue with PDF inside UIScrollView

Tags: cocoa-touch, pdf, ipad, uikit, uiscrollview

I have a UIView subclass which displays a PDF, and this is embedded in a UIScrollView.  When the user zooms in, the PDF content is pixelated.  I've double checked, and anti-aliasing is enabled.  If I display the PDF at a larger size using CGContextScaleCTM, it displays fine, but I don't know how to integrate this with the UIScrollView zooming.  Is this possible, or should I eliminate the UIScrollView and handle the scrolling and zooming myself?

Comment: I've got the same issue.  Any answers yet?